# Choosing between composite components inside ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I have something like `<ui:repeat value="#{list}" var="a" />` where `list` is of type `List<Action>` and contains various objects that extend `Action`. Depending on the actual type of `Action`, I want to render a different composite component (for example, for `ActionA` I want to render component `A` and for `ActionB` I want to render `B`, where `B` would throw an exception if it were to get a value of type `ActionA`). How can I do this? It seems that using `rendered="#{a.type == 'ACTION_A'}"` (where `type` is a property of `Action`) on the composite components doesn't work as each iteration of `ui:repeat` adds all components to the tree so it sends the value `a` to each composite.

Thank you.

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: It looks like:

`<ui:repeat value="#{list}" var="a">
  <my:compa value="#{a}" rendered="#{a.type == 'ACTION_A'}" />
  <my:compb value="#{a}" rendered="#{a.type == 'ACTION_B'}" />
</ui:repeat>`

Comment: instead of repeat try with datatable.

Comment: @vels4j I do not understand how a datatable could help in my particular use case. Could you provide an example?